# How to create multiple setup applications with one .iss config?

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible for one .iss file to produce different setup exes at the same time? maybe with multiple [Setup] sections?

Comment: To make it easy I use multiple .iss files.

Comment: @Jimmy, agree! That's even more handy and if you need to, you can build them all at once e.g. from a batch file or some build automation software.

Comment: @TLama Yes, as long as you give the output files different names. That is what I do, so I can run more than one .iss file at a time and they won't interfere with each other.

Comment: @Jimmy, good point to mention the `OutputBaseFilename` directive.

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to create more than one output setup exe at the same time, but it is possible to create more than one from a single script.

The key is to use ISPP's `#define` and `#ifdef` or `#if` directives to designate parts of your script which are only compiled if specific variables are defined or given a particular value.  You can then use a batch script to invoke `iscc` with the `/dVAR` or `/dVAR="VALUE"` parameters (which are the equivalent of a `#define`) to select different conditions for each compile.

This is only really useful if the scripts are largely the same, however (eg. if you want to make separate installers for different "editions" of an application, instead of including all files for the largest edition and deciding at runtime which to install).  If your scripts are completely different from each other, then you should just create separate scripts and compile them from a batch file or an automated build script.

Comment: What does conditional preprocessing (by as you say using `#define and #ifdef or #if` directives, what says absolutely nothing, anyway) of one setup has to do with two setups in one script what has been asked here ? You just can't put two setups into one script and conditional preprocessing will do nothing with it.

Comment: It depends how similar they are, as I said. If you're wanting to make a Standard Edition and Pro edition installer, then you can put both in the same script file by using #ifdef PRO around the bits that shouldn't be in Standard, and then compile both from the command line with `iscc yourapp.iss` and `iscc /dPRO yourapp.iss`. Voila, two different installers created from one script. The rest should be obvious if you read the help file and what I wrote above.

Comment: Thanks; nice description (in comment)! Now even I understood what you meant :-)

Answer (score 3):

***Test result:***

By running a simple test... No, this is not possible. At first you can introduce sections on several places in a script. Consider you can do the following in your script:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program 1
AppVersion=1.5

[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"

[Setup]
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
```

From that you can see that compiler wouldn't recognize which one of the `[Setup]` sections belongs to which setup if you could write the script for more of them in one script file.

***Workaround:***

However, if you need to automate the build process on a basic level, you can create a batch file and run the compiler through the command line for all of your scripts. See [`the reference`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_compilercmdline.htm) about command line compiler usage.

If you will compile several scripts with the same output directory, don't forget to specify different value of the [`OutputBaseFilename`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_outputbasefilename) directive (the output exe name) for each script file.